# Solapar dos imagenes usando Glide en Android

Tags: java, android

Reedito la pregunta para que se entienda mejor de lo que pretendo realizar

Estoy realizando una vista detalle con la `actionbar` expansible

En la [guia de estilo de google](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration) se especifica que si la imagen es muy clara, mejor ponerle un degradado oscuro encima, para así resaltar si el texto es claro (blanco).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se puede solapar dos imágenes usando la librería Glide en Android?

Comment: no entiendo bien, quieres alguna de las 2 opciones o las quieres combinar? en ese caso, de que manera?

Comment: overlay normal, la que quiero poner encima es un degradado de negro a blanco con canal alpha (opaco a transparente)

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente yo cargo mediante `Glide` la imagen dentro mi `ImageView`:

```
backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_video);
String url = "https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png";
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(backdrop);
```

Dentro de mi `Layout` tengo definido como background para mi `ImageView` una imagen con un degradado (`sombra_video`):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_video"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/sombra_video"/>
```

Esto para evitar que la imagen que se cargue se pierda cuando el fondo es del mismo color, para eso la imagen "`sombra_video`".

Este es un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero el background asignado sombra_video no queda remplazado cuando se ha cargado mediante glide?

Comment: Si, obviamente la imagen que cargas debe ser una transparencia, revisa la imagen que anexe.